# VBScript exporting table relations from MSACCESS to put them back in later

Tags: ms-access, version-control, vbscript, table-relationships

For source control I am trying to export the table relations from Access in order to be able to re-import them. From what I can tell in order to do this I only need four pieces of information.

1. Table Name
2. Table Field Name
3. Foreign Table Name
4. Foreign Table Field Name

I got the first three down, but having an issue figuring out the last bit of information. Usually my tables and field names are always the same so it is generally not a problem but I would really like if this vbscript can account for times in the future where maybe perhaps it is not as evident. Here is a snippit of the code I am using:

```
Dim db, totalrelations, i, j

Set db = oApplication.CurrentDb
totalrelations = db.Relations.Count
WScript.Echo totalrelations
If totalrelations > 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "opening " & totalrelations
    For i = totalrelations - 1 To 0 Step -1
       'WScript.Echo (db.Relations(i).Name)
       'WScript.Echo (db.Relations.Item(i).name)

       WScript.Echo "Attributes: " &       db.Relations.Item(i).Attributes

 '**            'iterate through the count!!!
       WScript.Echo "Field count: " & db.Relations.Item(i).Fields.Count

       If db.Relations.Item(i).Fields.Count > 0 Then
            For j = 0 To db.Relations.Item(i).Fields.Count - 1
                WScript.Echo j & " Field name: " & db.Relations.Item(i).Fields.Item(j).Name
            Next 
       End If
       WScript.Echo "ForeignTable: " &     db.Relations.Item(i).ForeignTable
       WScript.Echo "Name: " &             db.Relations.Item(i).Name
       WScript.Echo "PartialReplica: " &   db.Relations.Item(i).PartialReplica

       WScript.Echo "propertycount: " & db.Relations.Item(i).Properties.Count
       'Simply repeats everything we already know
       If db.Relations.Item(i).Properties.Count > 0 Then
            For j = 0 To db.Relations.Item(i).Properties.Count -1
                WScript.echo j & " PropertyName:" & db.Relations.Item(i).Properties.Item(j).Name
                WScript.echo j & " PropertyValue:" & db.Relations.Item(i).Properties.Item(j).Value
            Next
       End if

       WScript.Echo "Table: " &            db.Relations.Item(i).Table
    Next 

End If
```

I had assumed that I could be clever and check the field counts and iterate through those. However the joke is on me as I made a relationship between two fields that do not share the same name and the field count remains 1. Thus my cleverness did not reveal to me the secret of mana :P Does anybody know how I can coax this information out?

1. Table Name =   db.Relations.Item.Table
2. Table Field Name = db.Relations.Item.Fields.Item(0).Name
3. Foreign Table Name = db.Relations.Item.ForeignTable
4. Foreign Table Field Name = ????

Comment: the code answer for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354651/importing-exporting-relationships-in-ms-access is fairly similar but the fields come out empty. (At least in it's vbscript adaptation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this ...

```
" Field name: " & db.Relations.Item(i).Fields.Item(j).Name
```

To retrieve the name of the related field in the foreign table, use this:

```
" Foreign Field name: " & db.Relations.Item(i).Fields.Item(j).ForeignName
```

Actually you don't need to explicitly include `.Item()` to retrieve the *ith* or *jth* member of each collection.  So I would shorten it to this:

```
" Foreign Field name: " & db.Relations(i).Fields(j).ForeignName
```

Comment: haha, wow now that you put it that way it seems so obvious haha. I lack complete experience on researching vb objects. Thank you so much!!