# Automatically Generate SQL from existing MS Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, schema

I've just designed a large database by playing around in MS Access. Now that I'm happy with the design, I need to be able to generate this same database (tables, relationships, etc.) from code.

Rather than hand-writing the SQL CREATE statements (which will be long, tedious, and error-prone process), I was wondering whether there was a shortcut. I seem to recall from my limited exposure to MySql that I was able to export an entire database as an SQL statement that can then be run in order to regenerate that database.

Do you know of a way to do this in MS Access, either through the GUI, or programmatically?

Comment: I have previously written some notes in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698839/how-to-extract-the-schema-of-an-access-mdb-database/699516#699516

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For free for 30 days (then $30) you can give [DBWScript](http://dbweigher.com/dbwscript.php) a go, looks like its what you are asking for, although not in native Access GUI or programmatically

Answer (score 12):

I just found and tried out this tool: [jet-tool](https://github.com/himselfv/jet-tool). It seems to work well for Access 2010.

Comment: needed a 2003 access database (mdb) instead of 2016 (accdb)

Comment: Looks like it does support mdb format, at least in the last version.

Answer (score 5):

The quick and dirty, easy, perfectly legitimate way to do this is just copy the .mdb file. Empty out the data if you need to - usually there are static tables that are handy to leave populated, however.

Comment: +1 - Hehe - hadn't really considered that. Funny how the simplest solutions are often the ones you overlook. Unfortunately, our product may be released as a standalone executable, so probably not plausible in this case. Although I guess we could somehow embed the binary data in the exe...

Answer (score 4):

I don't know what tools you have on your development machine, so this may or may not be helpful.

You can easily transfer your Access database to Microsoft SQL Server using the [Upsizing Wizard](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/237980).

The express edition of SQL Server is available for free > [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7522a683-4cb2-454e-b908-e805e9bd4e28).

You will also want to get the free [Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b).

Using these free graphical-based tools you can easily generate the SQL statements to re-create the database. You will have the Create statements you are looking for and they will be placed in a text file.

Answer (score 4):

I use a free utility called MDB Viewer Plus (http://www.alexnolan.net/software/mdb_viewer_plus.htm).
Launch it, open your db, then select your table.
On top menu, select "Table > Generate SQL - CREATE".

Comment: This worked well for me, thank you. As a side note, for some reason you cannot download the MDB Viewer Plus directly from Alex Nolan's website. It is available on several public software archives.

Comment: Bad news. I downloaded MDB Viewer Plus Version 2.63 and the option "Table > Generate SQL - CREATE" is missing.

Comment: You can find v.2.52 here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=00286856232743084617. This version still has the export option.

Answer (score 4):

The Bullzip is very good to this. Very simple. See [bullzip Access to MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) for example

It is possible export any tables to SQL or migrate automatically.

> Access to MySQL is a small program that will convert Microsoft Access Databases to MySQL.
>
> - Wizard interface.
> - Transfer data directly from one server to another.
> - Create a dump file.
> - Select tables to transfer.
> - Select fields to transfer.
> - Transfer password protected databases.
> - Supports both shared security and user-level security.
> - Optional transfer of indexes.
> - Optional transfer of records.
> - Optional transfer of default values in field definitions.
> - Identifies and transfers auto number field types.
> - Command line interface.
> - Easy install, uninstall and upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

The thing that you're mentioning in MySQL is sql dumping. Very useful feature. If you want to migrate the database to mysql, here's a helpful article.

http://www.kitebird.com/articles/access-migrate.html#TOC_4

Answer (score 0):

I have been using for years a tool called **database.net** from https://fishcodelib.com/Database.htm
I generally use it on client's site as a portable version of SSMS (drop and run), but it can handle a multitude of RDBMSes, including Access.
Connect to your mdb/accdb, right click any table, choose SCRIPT AS, Create, and you're done.
If you right click Tables header, you can select multiple tables to generate, but I think it's a feature of the paid version.
I have no acquaintance with them, just a happy client.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to go:

[Export-> ODBC Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbtA1.png)

and then retrieve the SQL form there (e.g via pgadmin on postgres)

Answer (score -1):

Compare'Em
http://home.gci.net/~mike-noel/CompareEM-LITE/CompareEM.htm
The free version creates VBA while the $10 pro version gives you DDL statements.