# Export all queries of an access database with powershell

Tags: powershell, ms-access, com

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275502/using-vba-to-export-all-ms-access-sql-queries-to-text-files) demonstrates how to do it with VBA, but I would like to do it with PowerShell, so it can be scripted and scheduled.

I expected the implementation should be identical as they both allegedly use the same COM but it seems `QueryDefs` is not defined in the COM that PowerShell accesses as it returns nothing.

```
# Open file in Access.
$accessCOM = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application
$accessCOM.OpenCurrentDataBase($dbPath, $false)

# get list of queries
$queries = $accessCOM.CurrentDB.QueryDefs # returns nothing.

# export query to file
ForEach ($query in $queries) {
    $name = $query.name
    $sql = $query.sql
    $dest = "$queryDest\$name.sql"
    Write-Output $sql > $dest
}
```

I can use `.CurrentData.AllQueries` but that returns a collection of AccessObjects and I don't know how to get the SQL from them.  Is there any other way to get the QueryDefs or at least the SQL from the name?

Comment: What does `$accessCOM.CurrentDB.Name` show you?

Comment: "CurrentDb" which is not the name of the .accdb file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me with Access 2010. It just dumps the names of the non-system QueryDefs to the console, but it should get you started:

```ps
$dbe = New-Object -com DAO.DBEngine.120
$db = $dbe.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb")
$queries = $db.QueryDefs
ForEach ($query in $queries) {
    $name = $query.Name
    If (!$name.StartsWith("~")) {
        $name
    }
}
```

Comment: I added how I opened the database in powershell as it's different than yours.  Hopefully your method will work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this modification to the previous post. Worked for me.
After you run it once, other properties of the variables will be available in the PowerShell ISE through IntelliSense.

```
$dbe = New-Object -com DAO.DBEngine.120
$dbpath ="path/to/data.mdb"
$db = $dbe.OpenDatabase($dbpath,$false,$false,";pwd=r3ealLy?")
$queries = $db.QueryDefs
ForEach ($query in $queries) {
    $name = $query.Name
    If (!$name.StartsWith("~")) {
       $name + ":"
       $query.SQL
    }
}
```