# Export and Import MS Access table definitions as text files

Tags: ms-access, vba

How can I export/import MS Access table definitions as text files (in a human readable format like I can with Forms or Reports)?

I know how I can export the whole table out into CSV file; however:

- I don't need the data to go (actually really rather that it didn't)
- When I import a CSV file (especially without data) there's no guarantee that the data types will be the same as my original database.

I'm hoping to store my table definitions in a SVN repository.
I don't want to have to house any import specifications in the destination database.

Comment: Cross-reference:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/187506/how-do-you-use-version-control-with-access-development
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/698839/how-to-extract-the-schema-of-an-access-mdb-database/9910716#9910716

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the ExportXML method.  I have used it to export both table data and structure.  However, based on a quick test, it appears you can drop the DataTarget option, and just export SchemaTarget.

```
Application.ExportXML _
    ObjectType:=acExportTable, _
    DataSource:="tblFoo", _
    DataTarget:="tblFoo.xml"
    SchemaTarget:="tblFooSchema.xsd"
```

Comment: And you can use the Application.ImportXML to bring it back in.

Application.ImportXML _
    DataSource:="tblFooSchema.xml", _
    ImportOptions:=acStructureOnly

Answer (score 0):

If you need to export DAO specific properties, like title, validation text, etc, you can use [AccessSVN](http://accesssvn.codeplex.com).
The export format is much like the *SaveAsText* function for forms or queries.
And also, you can import back the schema.