# query for ms access

Tags: sql, ms-access

my query is `"SELECT column_name, table_name FROM information_schema.columns"`
.but it execute true in sqlserver ,but it dosn't execute true 
in Ms Access.i want to get all colums and tables'name from specific
database.thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look to this question: [How to extract the schema of an Access (.mdb) database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698839/how-to-extract-the-schema-of-an-access-mdb-database)