# Is there an method to get Metadata of tables and columns out of Access to export to Excel

Tags: ms-access, export-to-excel

I'm looking for an output/export of all table names, column names & datatypes from MS Access into Excel.

I started to play around with 'MSysObjects' but also read on SO these tables should not be used.

I thought this would be fairly easy on the interweb, but not that many resources. I tried a VBA script from another thread, but I have no experience with VBA and I could not make it work.

Comment: Can query system tables, just don't edit their records. Show attempted code and describe issues encountered. What does 'could not make it work' mean - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Question as is will likely be closed as inappropriate for SO.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698839/how-to-extract-the-schema-of-an-access-mdb-database