# Alternative to Application.LoadFromText for MS Access Queries

Tags: ms-access, vba, vbscript

I am attempting to load from text files, queries into an MS Access Queries Collection using VBScript. I am using something like this:
 The code originated from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187506/how-do-you-use-version-control-with-access-development).

```
 for each myFile in folder.Files
    objecttype = fso.GetExtensionName(myFile.Name)
    objectname = fso.GetBaseName(myFile.Name)
    WScript.Echo "  " & objectname & " (" & objecttype & ")"

    if (objecttype = "form") then
        oApplication.LoadFromText acForm, objectname, myFile.Path
    elseif (objecttype = "bas") then
        oApplication.LoadFromText acModule, objectname, myFile.Path
    elseif (objecttype = "mac") then
        oApplication.LoadFromText acMacro, objectname, myFile.Path
    elseif (objecttype = "report") then
        oApplication.LoadFromText acReport, objectname, myFile.Path
    elseif (objecttype = "sql") then
        'oApplication.LoadFromText acQuery, objectname, myFile.Path
        ' Add create querydef code here
    end if

 next
```

But I am unsure how to create a query definition using VBScript.

Any ideas?

Note:
I originally Exported to the file using something like this:

```
For Each myObj In oApplication.CurrentDb.QueryDefs 
   Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(sExportpath & "\" & myObj.Name & ".sql", True) 
   f.WriteLine(myObj.SQL) 
   f.Close 
Next
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This saves the query defs

```
For i = 0 To db.QueryDefs.Count - 1
    Application.SaveAsText acQuery, db.QueryDefs(i).Name, sExportpath & "\" & db.QueryDefs(i).Name & ".sql"
Next i
```

Then the LoadFromText should work

Comment: Although rare, when you have a query that has a subquery as an input table, LoadFromText will work, but will create a corrupt query.  Inside the exported query txt file, there will be a section with "Begin InputTables" and the table "Name" value will be your subquery SQL.   After the import, access interprets this name as a querydef name. The workaround is to parse the query export file, look for subqueries, and "unpack" them during the export process. I ran into this because I had to write an auto-fix routine that cleaned out corrupted binary blocks from Access Objects.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness I wanted to add my solution.

```
if (objecttype = "form") then
    oApplication.LoadFromText acForm, objectname, myFile.Path
elseif (objecttype = "bas") then
    oApplication.LoadFromText acModule, objectname, myFile.Path
elseif (objecttype = "mac") then
    oApplication.LoadFromText acMacro, objectname, myFile.Path
elseif (objecttype = "report") then
    oApplication.LoadFromText acReport, objectname, myFile.Path
elseif (objecttype = "sql") then
    oApplication.LoadFromText acQuery, objectname, myFile.Path
end if
```

Apparently all that needed to be added was:

```
  Const acQuery = 1
```

Thanks to DJ