# Source Code Control / Version Control in MS Access

Tags: version-control, ms-access-2010

This is a general question about the topic. I ran across a **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187506/how-do-you-use-version-control-with-access-development)** which gave VB script code for version control. I've been developing with Access for a while, but have learned entirely on my own and can be pretty ignorant of the the broader IT world. I got 
the code to work for me, but I'm lost on how to put it to work as a system.

To give some context, I have an example situation that maybe this kind of thing could solve. I'm now working on two versions at once (1.2 and 1.3) because the first version we'd like to release has to be tested where it's to be used in China. They were out of the office for a week due to the Chinese new year, in the meantime, I'm working on 1.3. Now, any changes I have to make to 1.2 of course have to go into 1.3. Actually, it's worse than that because clarity over the fact that we'd have to do this in two separate releases didn't emerge until work had been done which in hindsight went further than we could incorporate in 1.2.

The code in the post basically dumps all of the info about forms, reports, VBA, and macros into a bunch of text files (for some reason not tables, and maybe that has something to do with the fact that I'm working with Access 2010 rather than whatever version this code was created for.) Apparently, it can then reconstruct an application from those same text files.

What do I need to understand about source code control to make such a thing work for me? I recognize that might not be something you'd want to explain in a post, but can you point me in the right direction information-wise?

Comment: if i understand ur post correctly, you are not using any source control products? with Access 2007 Developer Extensions, you can integrate a source control program with Access. here is a post about [Using Visual SourceSafe – Integrating VSS with Access 2007](http://www.kevingao.net/version-control/sourcesafe/integrating-sourcesafe-vss-with-access-2007.html) for your reference.

Comment: It sounds like I'd need Visual Studio to be able to use VSS. VSS also seems to be highly unpopular. Are there any free/low cost solutions out there that would integrate with Access Developer Extensions?

Comment: subversion is a free product which should be able to be integrated with Access. see [accesssvn.codeplex.com](http://accesssvn.codeplex.com). if you want to go with a commercial product, you may consider [this one](http://kb.dynamsoft.com/questions/478/How+to+integrate+SourceAnywhere+Hosted+with+MS+Access%3F)

Answer (score 3):

While this question is 3 years old, it might be of interest to some to have an answer anyway.
AFAIK, accesssvn.codeplex.com -cited by @Robby Shaw - is not working and not maintained.
Today I see 2 products usable products for VCS inegration:

- one is https://github.com/timabell/msaccess-vcs-integration which is quite active
- the other one is [Microsoft Access 2010 Source Code Control](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6840) for which I don't know if it works with more recent versions of Access

Apart from VCS, you could also use a database compare tool like Microsoft's [Database Compare 2013](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Compare-two-versions-of-a-database-Database-Compare-a969a77a-5251-4b59-84ea-74e12a135a05)

Also worth considering, Accdbmerge, a [tool to merge 2 databases](https://db-merge-tools.net/microsoft-access-diff-merge-overview.html).