# Git detects changes in files when there is none

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have an Access Database that needs to be versioned on a per module bases. I used [this script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187506/how-do-you-use-version-control-with-access-development) to export out all the code into separate text files and into a git repo.

The problem that I'm having is that the script exports the files even if they haven't changed. In otherwords, even though the contents of the file havnt changed, technically it becomes a new file with a new "created date".

When I push the commit to GitHub it acts as if every file changed and pushes every file in the commit.

This makes it impossible for more then one person to work on the project because everyone will keep overwriting each other when they commit. Thus defeating the purpose of the export script.

I'm attempting to try to alter the export script to compare the files before export and only export them if they are changed. But that is turning to be more trouble then I expected.

So in the mean time, My question is if there is something I can do on the Git side so that it only looks at the file contents and only commits the files that have truly changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has a built-in heuristic to determine if a file is text or binary, and depending on your client **may** correct newlines to the local platform, consistently causing it to appear changed. You can [force the files to be treated as binary](http://www.dont-panic.cc/capi/2009/02/16/how-to-force-git-to-consider-a-file-as-binary/) to avoid 'smart' behaviour like that.