# Bug with For Each enumeration on x64 Custom Classes

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit, enumeration, custom-collection

I have found a bug in VBA a few months ago and was unable to find a decent workaround. The bug is really annoying as it kind of restricts a nice language feature.

When using a Custom Collection Class it is quite common to want to have an enumerator so that the class can be used in a `For Each` loop. This can be done by adding this line:

```
Attribute [MethodName].VB_UserMemId = -4 'The reserved DISPID_NEWENUM
```

immediately after the function/property signature line either by:

1. Exporting the class module, editing the contents in a text editor, and then importing back
2. Using [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) annotation `'@Enumerator` above the function signature and then syncronizing

Unfortunately, on x64, using the above-mentioned feature, causes the wrong memory to get written and leads to the crash of the Application in certain cases (discussed later).

**Reproducing the bug**

`CustomCollection` class:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "CustomCollection"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private m_coll As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_coll = New Collection
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_coll = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Add(v As Variant)
    m_coll.Add v
End Sub

Public Function NewEnum() As IEnumVARIANT
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set NewEnum = m_coll.[_NewEnum]
End Function
```

Code in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim c As New CustomCollection
        c.Add 1
        c.Add 2
        ShowBug c
    #Else
        MsgBox "This bug does not occur on 32 bits!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
    #End If
End Sub

Sub ShowBug(c As CustomCollection)
    Dim ptr0 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr1 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr2 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr3 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr4 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr5 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr6 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr7 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr8 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr9 As LongPtr
    '
    Dim v As Variant
    '
    For Each v In c
    Next v
    Debug.Assert ptr0 = 0
End Sub
```

By running the `Main` method, the code will stop on the `Assert` line in the `ShowBug` method and you can see in the *Locals* window that local variables got their values changed out of nowhere:
[image]
where ptr1 is equal to `ObjPtr(c)`. The more variables are used inside the `NewEnum` method (including Optional parameters) the more ptrs in the `ShowBug` method get written with a value (memory address).

Needless to say, removing the local *ptr* variables inside the `ShowBug` method would most certainly cause the crash of the Application.

When stepping through code line by line, this bug will not occur!

---

**More on the bug**

The bug is not related with the actual `Collection` stored inside the `CustomCollection`. The memory gets written immediately after the NewEnum function is invoked. So, basically doing any of the following is not helping (tested):

1. adding `Optional` parameters
2. removing all code from within the function (see below code showing this)
3. declaring as `IUnknown` instead of `IEnumVariant`
4. instead of `Function` declaring as `Property Get`
5. using keywords like `Friend` or `Static` in the method signature
6. adding the DISPID_NEWENUM to a *Let* or *Set* counterpart of the *Get*, or even hiding the former (i.e. make the Let/Set private).

Let us try step 2 mentioned above. If `CustomCollection` becomes:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "CustomCollection"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Public Function NewEnum() As IEnumVARIANT
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
End Function
```

and the code used for testing is changed to:

```
Sub Main()
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim c As New CustomCollection
        ShowBug c
    #Else
        MsgBox "This bug does not occur on 32 bits!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
    #End If
End Sub

Sub ShowBug(c As CustomCollection)
    Dim ptr0 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr1 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr2 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr3 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr4 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr5 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr6 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr7 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr8 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr9 As LongPtr
    '
    Dim v As Variant
    '
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each v In c
    Next v
    On Error GoTo 0
    Debug.Assert ptr0 = 0
End Sub
```

running `Main` produces the same bug.

**Workaround**

Reliable ways, that I found, to avoid the bug:

1. Call a method (basically leave the `ShowBug` method) and come back. This needs to happen before the `For Each` line is executed (*before* meaning it can be anywhere in the same method, not necessarily the exact line before):

   ```
   Sin 0 'Or VBA.Int 1 - you get the idea
   For Each v In c
   Next v
   ```

   Cons: Easy to forget
2. Do a `Set` statement. It could be on the variant used in the loop (if no other objects are used). As in point 1 above, this needs to happen before the `For Each` line is executed:

   ```
   Set v = Nothing
   For Each v In c
   Next v
   ```

   or even by setting the collection to itself with `Set c = c`
   Or, passing the **c** parameter `ByVal` to the `ShowBug` method (which, as Set, does a call to IUnknown::AddRef)
   Cons: Easy to forget
3. Using a separate `EnumHelper` class that is the only class ever used for enumerating:

   ```
   VERSION 1.0 CLASS
   BEGIN
     MultiUse = -1  'True
   END
   Attribute VB_Name = "EnumHelper"
   Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
   Attribute VB_Creatable = False
   Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
   Attribute VB_Exposed = False
   Option Explicit

   Private m_enum As IEnumVARIANT

   Public Property Set EnumVariant(newEnum_ As IEnumVARIANT)
       Set m_enum = newEnum_
   End Property
   Public Property Get EnumVariant() As IEnumVARIANT
   Attribute EnumVariant.VB_UserMemId = -4
       Set EnumVariant = m_enum
   End Property
   ```

   `CustomCollection` would become:

   ```
   VERSION 1.0 CLASS
   BEGIN
     MultiUse = -1  'True
   END
   Attribute VB_Name = "CustomCollection"
   Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
   Attribute VB_Creatable = False
   Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
   Attribute VB_Exposed = False
   Option Explicit

   Private m_coll As Collection

   Private Sub Class_Initialize()
       Set m_coll = New Collection
   End Sub
   Private Sub Class_Terminate()
       Set m_coll = Nothing
   End Sub

   Public Sub Add(v As Variant)
       m_coll.Add v
   End Sub

   Public Function NewEnum() As EnumHelper
       Dim eHelper As New EnumHelper
       '
       Set eHelper.EnumVariant = m_coll.[_NewEnum]
       Set NewEnum = eHelper
   End Function
   ```

   and the calling code:

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Sub Main()
       #If Win64 Then
           Dim c As New CustomCollection
           c.Add 1
           c.Add 2
           ShowBug c
       #Else
           MsgBox "This bug does not occur on 32 bits!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
       #End If
   End Sub

   Sub ShowBug(c As CustomCollection)
       Dim ptr0 As LongPtr
       Dim ptr1 As LongPtr
       Dim ptr2 As LongPtr
       Dim ptr3 As LongPtr
       Dim ptr4 As LongPtr
       Dim ptr5 As LongPtr
       Dim ptr6 As LongPtr
       Dim ptr7 As LongPtr
       Dim ptr8 As LongPtr
       Dim ptr9 As LongPtr
       '
       Dim v As Variant
       '
       For Each v In c.NewEnum
           Debug.Print v
       Next v
       Debug.Assert ptr0 = 0
   End Sub
   ```

   Obviously, the reserved DISPID was removed from the `CustomCollection` class.

   Pros: forcing the `For Each` on the `.NewEnum` function instead of the custom collection directly. This avoids any crash caused by the bug.

   Cons: always needing the extra `EnumHelper` class. Easy to forget to add the `.NewEnum` in the `For Each` line (would only trigger a runtime error).

The last approach (3) works because when `c.NewEnum` is executed the `ShowBug` method is exited and then returned before the invocation of the `Property Get EnumVariant` inside the `EnumHelper` class. Basically approach (1) is the one avoiding the bug.

---

What is the explanation for this behavior? Can this bug be avoided in a more elegant way?

**EDIT**

Passing the `CustomCollection` ByVal is not always an option. Consider a `Class1`:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_collection As CustomCollection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_collection = New CustomCollection
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_collection = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub AddElem(d As Double)
    m_collection.Add d
End Sub

Public Function SumElements() As Double
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim s As Double
    
    For Each v In m_collection
        s = s + v
    Next v
    SumElements = s
End Function
```

And now a calling routine:

```
Sub ForceBug()
    Dim c As Class1
    Set c = New Class1
    c.AddElem 2
    c.AddElem 5
    c.AddElem 7
    
    Debug.Print c.SumElements 'BOOM - Application crashes
End Sub
```

Obviously, the example is a bit forced but it is quite common to have a "parent" object containing a Custom Collection of "child" objects and the "parent" might want to do some operation involving some or all of the "children".

In this case it would be easy to forget to do a `Set` statement or a method call before the `For Each` line.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221369/discussion-on-question-by-cristian-buse-bug-with-for-each-enumeration-on-x64-cus).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**What is happening**

It appears that the [stack frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Structure) are overlapping although they should not. Having enough variables in the `ShowBug` method prevents a crash and the values of the variables (in the caller subroutine) are simply changed because the memory they refer to is also used by another stack frame (the called subroutine) that was added/pushed later at the top of the call stack.

We can test this by adding a couple of `Debug.Print` statements to the same code from the question.

The `CustomCollection` class:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "CustomCollection"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private m_coll As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_coll = New Collection
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_coll = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Add(v As Variant)
    m_coll.Add v
End Sub

Public Function NewEnum() As IEnumVARIANT
Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Debug.Print "The NewEnum return address " & VarPtr(NewEnum) & " should be outside of the"
    Set NewEnum = m_coll.[_NewEnum]
End Function
```

And the calling code, in a standard .bas module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim c As New CustomCollection
        c.Add 1
        c.Add 2
        ShowBug c
    #Else
        MsgBox "This bug does not occur on 32 bits!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
    #End If
End Sub

Sub ShowBug(ByRef c As CustomCollection)
    Dim ptr0 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr1 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr2 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr3 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr4 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr5 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr6 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr7 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr8 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr9 As LongPtr
    '
    Dim v As Variant
    '
    For Each v In c
    Next v
    Debug.Print VarPtr(ptr9) & " - " & VarPtr(ptr0) & " memory range"
    Debug.Assert ptr0 = 0
End Sub
```

By running `Main` I get something like this in the Immediate Window:
[image]

The address of the `NewEnum` return value is clearly at a memory address in between the `ptr0` and `ptr9` variables of the `ShowBug` method. So, that is why the variables get values out of nowhere, because they actually come from the stack frame of the `NewEnum` method (like the address of the object's vtable or the address of the `IEnumVariant` interface). If the variables would not be there, then the crash is obvious as more critical parts of memory are being overwritten (e.g. the frame pointer address for the `ShowBug` method). As the stack frame for the `NewEnum` method is larger (we can add local variables for example, to increase the size), the more memory is shared between the top stack frame and the one below in the call stack.

What happens if we workaround the bug with the options described in the question? Simply adding a `Set v = Nothing` before the `For Each v In c` line, results into:
[image]

Showing both previous value and the current one (bordered blue), we can see that the `NewEnum` return is at a memory address outside of the `ptr0` and `ptr9` variables of the `ShowBug` method. It seems that the stack frame was correctly allocated using the workaround.

If we break inside the `NewEnum` the call stack looks like this:
[image]

**How `For Each` invokes `NewEnum`**

Every VBA class is derived from [IDispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch) (which in turn is derived from IUnknown).

When a `For Each...` loop is called on an object, that object's `IDispatch::Invoke` method is called with a `dispIDMember` equal to -4. A VBA.Collection already has such a member but for VBA custom classes we mark our own method with `Attribute NewEnum.VB_UserMemId = -4` so that Invoke can call our method.

`Invoke` is not called directly if the interface used in the `For Each` line is not derived from `IDispatch`. Instead, `IUnknown::QueryInterface` is called first and asked for the IDispatch interface. In this case `Invoke` is obviously called
only after IDispatch interface is returned. Right here is the reason why using `For Each` on an Object declared `As IUnknown` will not cause the bug regardless if it is passed `ByRef` or if it is a global or class member custom collection. It simply uses workaround number 1 mentioned in the question (i.e. calls another method) although we cannot see it.

**Hooking Invoke**

We can replace the non-VB `Invoke` method with one of our own in order to investigate further. In a standard `.bas` module we need the following code to hook:

```
Option Explicit

#If Mac Then
    #If VBA7 Then
        Private Declare PtrSafe Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr) As LongPtr
    #Else
        Private Declare Function CopyMemory Lib "/usr/lib/libc.dylib" Alias "memmove" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long) As Long
    #End If
#Else 'Windows
    'https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt723419(v=vs.85).aspx
    #If VBA7 Then
        Public Declare PtrSafe Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As LongPtr)
    #Else
        Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (Destination As Any, Source As Any, ByVal Length As Long)
    #End If
#End If

#If Win64 Then
    Private Const PTR_SIZE As Long = 8
#Else
    Private Const PTR_SIZE As Long = 4
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Private newInvokePtr As LongPtr
    Private oldInvokePtr As LongPtr
    Private invokeVtblPtr As LongPtr
#Else
    Private newInvokePtr As Long
    Private oldInvokePtr As Long
    Private invokeVtblPtr As Long
#End If

'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-invoke
Function IDispatch_Invoke(ByVal this As Object _
    , ByVal dispIDMember As Long _
    , ByVal riid As LongPtr _
    , ByVal lcid As Long _
    , ByVal wFlags As Integer _
    , ByVal pDispParams As LongPtr _
    , ByVal pVarResult As LongPtr _
    , ByVal pExcepInfo As LongPtr _
    , ByRef puArgErr As Long _
) As Long
    Const DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND = &H80020003
    '
    Debug.Print "The IDispatch::Invoke return address " & VarPtr(IDispatch_Invoke) & " should be outside of the"
    IDispatch_Invoke = DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND
End Function

Sub HookInvoke(obj As Object)
    If obj Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    #If VBA7 Then
        Dim vTablePtr As LongPtr
    #Else
        Dim vTablePtr As Long
    #End If
    '
    newInvokePtr = VBA.Int(AddressOf IDispatch_Invoke)
    CopyMemory vTablePtr, ByVal ObjPtr(obj), PTR_SIZE
    '
    invokeVtblPtr = vTablePtr + 6 * PTR_SIZE
    CopyMemory oldInvokePtr, ByVal invokeVtblPtr, PTR_SIZE
    CopyMemory ByVal invokeVtblPtr, newInvokePtr, PTR_SIZE
End Sub

Sub RestoreInvoke()
    If invokeVtblPtr = 0 Then Exit Sub
    '
    CopyMemory ByVal invokeVtblPtr, oldInvokePtr, PTR_SIZE
    invokeVtblPtr = 0
    oldInvokePtr = 0
    newInvokePtr = 0
End Sub
```

and we run the `Main2` method (standard .bas module) to produce the bug:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main2()
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim c As Object
        Set c = New CustomCollection
        c.Add 1
        c.Add 2
        '
        HookInvoke c
        ShowBug2 c
        RestoreInvoke
    #Else
        MsgBox "This bug does not occur on 32 bits!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
    #End If
End Sub

Sub ShowBug2(ByRef c As CustomCollection)
    Dim ptr00 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr01 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr02 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr03 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr04 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr05 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr06 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr07 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr08 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr09 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr10 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr11 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr12 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr13 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr14 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr15 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr16 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr17 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr18 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr19 As LongPtr
    '
    Dim v As Variant
    '
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each v In c
    Next v
    Debug.Print VarPtr(ptr19) & " - " & VarPtr(ptr00) & " range on the call stack"
    Debug.Assert ptr00 = 0
End Sub
```

<sup>*Notice that more dummy ptr variables are needed to prevent the crash as the stack frame for `IDispatch_Invoke` is bigger (hence, the memory overlap is bigger).*</sup>

By running the above, I get:
[image]

The same bug occurs although the code never reaches the `NewEnum` method due to the hooking of the `Invoke` method. The stack frame is again wrongfully allocated.

Again, adding a `Set v = Nothing` before the `For Each v In c` results into:
[image]

The stack frame is allocated correctly (bordered green). This indicates that the issue is not with the `NewEnum` method and also not with our replacement `Invoke` method. Something is happening before our `Invoke` is called.

If we break inside our `IDispatch_Invoke` the call stack looks like this:
[image]

One last example. Consider a blank (with no code) class `Class1`. If we run `Main3` in the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main3()
    #If Win64 Then
        Dim c As New Class1
        ShowBug3 c
    #Else
        MsgBox "This bug does not occur on 32 bits!", vbInformation, "Cancelled"
    #End If
End Sub

Sub ShowBug3(ByRef c As Class1)
    Dim ptr0 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr1 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr2 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr3 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr4 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr5 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr6 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr7 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr8 As LongPtr
    Dim ptr9 As LongPtr
    '
    Dim v As Variant
    '
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each v In c
    Next v
    Debug.Assert ptr0 = 0
End Sub
```

The bug simply does not occur. How is this different from running `Main2` with our own hooked `Invoke`? In both cases `DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND` is returned and no `NewEnum` method is called.

Well, if we look at the previously shown call stacks side by side:
[image]
we can see that the non-VB `Invoke` is not pushed on the VB stack as a separate "Non-Basic Code" entry.

Apparently, the bug only occurs if a VBA method is called (either NewEnum via the original non-VB Invoke or our own IDispatch_Invoke). If a non-VB method is called (like the original IDispatch::Invoke with no following NewEnum) the bug does not occur as in `Main3` above. No bug occurs when running `For Each...` on a VBA Collection within the same circumstances either.

**The bug cause**

As all the above examples suggest, the bug can be summarized with the following:
`For Each` calls `IDispatch::Invoke` which in turn calls `NewEnum` while the stack pointer has not been incremented with the size of the `ShowBug` stack frame. Hence, same memory is used by both frames (the caller `ShowBug` and the callee `NewEnum`).

**Workarounds**

Ways to force the correct incrementation of the stack pointer:

1. call another method directly (before the `For Each` line) e.g. `Sin 1`
2. call another method indirectly (before the `For Each` line):

   - a call to `IUnknown::AddRef` by passing the argument `ByVal`
   - a call to `IUnknown::QueryInterface` by using the `stdole.IUnknown` interface
   - using a `Set` statement which will call either `AddRef` or `Release` or both (e.g. `Set c = c`). Could also call `QueryInterface` depending on the source and target interfaces

As suggested in the **EDIT** section of the question, we don't always have the possibility to pass the Custom Collection class `ByVal` because it could simply be a global variable, or a class member and we would need to remember to do a dummy `Set` statement or to call another method before `For Each...` is executed.

**Solution**

I still could not find a better solution that the one presented in the question, so I am just going to replicate the code here as part of the answer, with a slight tweak.

`EnumHelper` class:

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
END
Attribute VB_Name = "EnumHelper"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = False
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = False
Attribute VB_Exposed = False
Option Explicit

Private m_enum As IEnumVARIANT

Public Property Set EnumVariant(newEnum_ As IEnumVARIANT)
    Set m_enum = newEnum_
End Property
Public Property Get EnumVariant() As IEnumVARIANT
Attribute EnumVariant.VB_UserMemId = -4
    Set EnumVariant = m_enum
End Property

Public Property Get Self() As EnumHelper
    Set Self = Me
End Property
```

`CustomCollection` would now become something like:

```
Option Explicit

Private m_coll As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_coll = New Collection
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_coll = Nothing
End Sub

Public Sub Add(v As Variant)
    m_coll.Add v
End Sub

Public Function NewEnum() As EnumHelper
    With New EnumHelper
        Set .EnumVariant = m_coll.[_NewEnum]
        Set NewEnum = .Self
    End With
End Function
```

You would just need to call with `For Each v in c.NewEnum`

Although, the `EnumHelper` class would be an extra class needed in any project implementing a custom collection class, there are a couple of advantages as well:

1. You would never need to add the `Attribute [MethodName].VB_UserMemId = -4`  to any other custom collection class. This is even more useful for users that do not have [RubberDuck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) installed (`'@Enumerator` annotation), as they would need to export, edit the .cls text file and import back for each custom collection class
2. You could expose multiple EnumHelpers for the same class. Consider a custom dictionary class. You could have an `ItemsEnum` and a `KeysEnum` at the same time. Both `For Each v in c.ItemsEnum` and `For Each v in c.KeysEnum` would work
3. You would never forget to use one of the workarounds presented above as the method exposing the `EnumHelper` class would be called before `Invoke` is calling member ID -4
4. You would not get crashes anymore. If you forget to call with `For Each v in c.NewEnum` and instead use `For Each v in c` you would just get a runtime error which would be picked up in testing anyway. Of course you could still force a crash by passing the result of `c.NewEnum` to another method `ByRef` which would then need to execute a `For Each` before any other method call or `Set` statement. Highly unlikely you would ever do that
5. Obvious but worth mentioning, you would use the same `EnumHelper` class for all the custom collection classes you might have in a project

Comment: That means really going in depth, very instructive! +:)

Comment: @T.M. Thanks! Was quite keen to workaround the issue so that I could still use the feature.

Answer (score 1):

I can't add a comment due to not having enough rep, nor can I use the chat section as that is frozen, but I wanted to add that I have come up against something that sounds eerily similar, and though I have yet to test any of the solutions presented here, it does seem that it is the same bug.

I've tried to describe it here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/464383/is-the-vba-64-bit-compiler-broken.html?childToView=545565#answer-545565

I'm hoping that testing will solve the issue for me as well, and if so you have my heartfelt thanks for investigating the issue and providing workarounds for what otherwise was meaning the code could not be ported to 64 bit VBA.

Comment: I tested this on several 32 and 64 bit machines including on MAC. The bug is related to Windows 64-bit only (at least on all the machines I've tested on). The workarounds presented in the original question worked on all machines so I am confident it will work for you as well. If you want to see a real life example you can go to [KeyedCollection](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-KeyedCollection) repository where I actually used the separate ```EnumHelper``` class to avoid the bug.

Comment: Of course, you can still use the other 2 workarounds (a ```Set``` statement or a method call) before the actual ```For... Each...``` loop but you will at least have to add a comment next to those lines so that they are not deleted by mistake by whoever maintains the code. Probably best to add a link to this SO question.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I can't add a solution, and I couldn't add a comment previously due to not having enough rep, so it's difficult to know how to be supportive to this posting when the only way I can do so is via an Answer rather than a comment...

Comment: Christian, re Windows 64 bit, the issue I have does not appear when using 32 bit Office on 64 bit Windows, only when using 64 bit Office on 64 bit Windows, hence that's why when I described my issue on the Microsoft site I thought it might be an issue with the 64 bit VBA compiler. I don't believe (though I stand to be corrected) that this is a 64 bit Windows problem, rather it's 64 bit Office...?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. The issue has nothing to do with Windows. It is a VBA specific issue for 64 bits. I also do not have the issue on Office 32-bit running on Win 64-bit. So, exactly what you said. I wrote the comment in a rush and haven't realized that I wrote the wrong thing. I meant that I tested on different machines with 32 and 64 bits VBA versions.

Comment: I can't test 32 bit Office on 32 Windows as the company I work for no longer has any 32 bit Windows PCs. However, I tested on 32 bit Office on more than one 64 bit Windows PC and the issue didn't appear.  When I tested on 64 bit Office on more than one 64 bit Windows PC, and issue appeared all times. This confusion over exactly where the bitness matters is quite common. It doesn't help that Microsoft uses the term 'Win64' for it's compiler constant that actually refers to the Office bitness, not the Windows bitness.

Comment: Indeed. However, I've tested on 32-bit Win with 32-bit Office and the issue is not there. So yeah, just Office 64-bit related issue.

Comment: I don't get notified when you write a comment that is not addressed to me. This is your "answer" section and I do not need to write your name because you get automatically notified. However, you should start your comments with @CristianBuse if you want me to get notified. Similarly, if you were to write a comment under my answer, I would get notified without the need for you to add my name. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236933/discussion-between-cristian-buse-and-ian-j).

Comment: @CristianBuse Will do. Apologies for not doing so earlier. I'm not used to the usage of @ and #. I'm a bit of a dinosaur when it comes to some things :)

Comment: No problem, click the link in the previous comment so that we can chat separately if needed. See you there.

Comment: This is a brilliant post @CristianBuse. Thank you so much for investigating and documenting in such detail. I'm a PowerPoint MVP and referred to this when asking Microsoft if there's any chance at all to fix the root cause. I tried the Set and Sin mechanisms to circumvent the bug but they don't work for my project in 64bit PowerPoint on Windows. I will try the enum class method next.

Comment: The enumerator helper class method does work for me.

Comment: @JamieGarroch-MVP Interesting. I only tested on Excel and Word and ```Set``` was working. Glad that at least the enumerator class works.