# How to capture form or report changes made in design view

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to have an audit log of any change made to a form or report in design view, with the control or object manipulated, when it was done and by whom.

However, in creating this, I am stumped on the very first and most basic task, which is figuring out whether Access has a central function that would record the event of calling up a form in design view. [Hence I have no code to show for this problem yet].

**What event or procedure in MS Access can I monitor (using VBA) to record when a form or report is called up in design view?**

Any pointer provided is appreciated. Or alternatively if someone can tell me with certainty that this is not feasible to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you with certainty that this is not possible. There is no such event.

The only thing available is the "Last modified" date, which you can read e.g. from `MSysObjects.DateUpdate`.

To track design changes, you may want to look here:
[How do you use version control with Access development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187506/how-do-you-use-version-control-with-access-development)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and definitive answer. I suspected as much, which is why posted here.

Comment: You could write a procedure on form opening, coupled with Andres answer, that if it's the first time it's been opened since, to dump the details of the form to a table, control name, type, left, top, sql etc, what you'd need, and then until that date changes, that will be your "version" information of the table.  Not an easy solution though :)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yeah I thought of a similar solution, but it seemed more of a work around, and as you said, highly work intensive. So much so that it kills the benefit I would derive from this... which is me knowing when users screw around in my database.

Comment: You could give .accde or .mde databases to your users, then they *can't* screw around. @rohrl77

Comment: @Andre This is likely the option I will go for... I was interested in knowing who has been monkeying around... because after things break "nobody" ever touched anything. And they'll swear by that.

Comment: You could split it, into a front end on each users machine and a server back end, then you'll find the user.  From personal experience, they'll still deny :)

Comment: Also, there is the option to export the contents of the database documenter which you could work with?