# MS Access Source code repository

Tags: ms-access, repository, source-control-explorer

I want to use the source code repository for the MS Access Project. The code Repository requirement is more for version control of the application than multiple users accessing it.

can anyone suggest a code repository to be used for this particular requirement

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use version control with Access development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187506/how-do-you-use-version-control-with-access-development)

Answer (score 0):

I use this VCS system for Access: https://github.com/NCPN/Access_VCS