# What does const acForm = 2 mean?

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, vba

I am new to VBA and VBS. I was trying to implement a version control for my Access and stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187506/how-do-you-use-version-control-with-access-development) StackOverflow post. I googled as much as I could to understand the code and now I understand about 50 percent of the code. I don't want to ask how the entire code works because I should figure it out myself. However, there are parts which I did not find in google.

Why are these lines of code necessary?

```
const acForm = 2
const acModule = 5
const acMacro = 4
const acReport = 3
```

P.S. I have successfully implemented this code. I just wanted to understand a bit more.

Comment: They are `constants` used to represent an `AcObjectType` in the `SaveAsText` method call. In this case using constants makes the code cleaner and easier to read. You could just as easily type the numbers into the `SaveAsText` method call but it is less maintainable etc.

Comment: @AlexP That is a better answer!

Comment: Also see this reference on [AcObjectType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.acobjecttype)

Comment: If this code were to run in Access VBA, the constants declarations wouldn't be necessary, because they are inbuilt in Access. But VBScript doesn't know them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Const is a statement

> [Declares constants for use in place of literal values.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/16twy8ed(v=vs.84))

They don't change value. In this case the variable name is `acForm` and its value remains 2 throughout your program and cannot be changed while the script is running.

Wherever you see `acForm` it means the value 2.

When using VBA, these values are usually initialized by setting a reference, in this case, to the Microsoft Access Object Library, and that reference is pre-set when using Access. But when writing a VBScript file, you can't set references, so you need to provide any constant or enum you want to use yourself.

Better explanation from @Lankymart: You can't change a Constant value programmatically.