# Retain created tables/queries in front-end database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an access database split which has two different types of users.  One base of users creates tables/queries on their local front-end.  When they get a new version of the front end they lose those tables/queries.

I want to establish a process for retaining/transferring them to the new front end. Has anyone done this before?

So I'm thinking something like this:

Before the front-end on the local machine gets replaced, compare the tables/queries against the network copy. Any tables/queries found should be exported/imported into the new version.

Any direction or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Never done this. Very odd. Why would users be allowed to modify db structure? Is it the same tables for all users? Build these tables into the master frontend.

Comment: If these users are creating temp tables and queries in support of reporting functions, I would suggest Excel. It has excellent integration with Access.

Comment: This question is very broad, but have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/187506/7296893) about version control. I'm using code like this to have an updater that pulls in new linked tables/queries/forms/modules while preserving user-created tables and queries.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick feedback.  All but 2 particular users will not be creating any tables or queries; this really is just for two users that while aren't developers will need to create queries and will need to run them from time to time.  Erik, I like your approach and will research that link.  It sounds like a solution that could work.

Comment: Why not give these special users another (blank) database to play with? That database could contain all linked tables but no frontend things like forms or reports that are to be updated with the new frontend version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very strange situation but this is what I would do, as long as all they are adding is tables/queries and not forms/reports/vba code.

These users can have their own Access file that they create their "personal" tables/queries and then link them to their copy of the front end. When you push a new front end all they have to do it re-link everything from their personal access file to their front end.

You can start the file by copying their current front end and deleting all forms/reports/modules but leave all tables (linked and local) and queries. Then delete these additions from their front end and link them from the copy. Train them to add new items to that copy and linking them instead of just adding them to the front end file.

Essentially give each of these users and additional data/back end file that is personal to them.