# Source Control Option for VBA Project

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am maintaining a VBA Access application and I would like to use a source control.  Is there a way to break up the VBA Application into components and reassemble them when needed?  We are currently using git on azure dev ops for our other projects so if we could implement that as the solution great.  Unforturnately, I can't figure out how to break it down to component pieces.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [How do you use version control with Access development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187506/how-do-you-use-version-control-with-access-development)

Comment: yes thank you.  No matter what way I searched for something like this all I got was trash.

Comment: [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2020/12/11/sync-project-with-files/) may help you.