# Determine which .accdb was used to create .accde

Tags: ms-access, frontend, ms-access-2016

Is it possible, by looking at something about a Microsoft Access 2016 .accde file, to figure out what .accdb file a user converted to create the exe only version of the database?

I have inherited a split database that is in bad shape. Everyone in our department uses their own personal .accde, cutely personalized with their name in the filename (not helpful). What I cannot figure out, based on the chaos of the LAN folder in which the database is located, is which .accdb file--if any of the ones in the folder--was actually used to create all of the .accde files everyone is using. There are five candidate .accdb front ends, all with similar Dates Modified.

I need to update the VBA in the .accdb and can't figure this out. Help?

Thank you,

KJ

Comment: If only five varieties, open the accdb files one by one and study its pecularities.

Comment: You can use methods from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187506/how-do-you-use-version-control-with-access-development) to make the comparison easier (using some diff tool on the text files).

Comment: Thank you for the link. I may have oversold the "only five candidates"; there are actually about 35 more files in a subfolder that could also be the .accdb.