# How do I print off the Design view of a MS Access report so that I can see the variables the report is referencing?

Tags: ms-access

Our engineering and document control departments want us to provide a PDF export of the design views of our MS Access reports, as they are populated by variables from the data tables. The departments want those variables shown.

Is there a way to do this besides taking a screenshot of the reports?

The only way we were able to find is screenshot. Print Preview exits the design view. And we are not sure what VBA code could be useful here.

Thank you!

Comment: Under Database Tools you have the Database Documenter option. You can selectively do only reports and if you browse the various options you can print as little or as much detail as you want.

Comment: What's wrong with screenshots? (Especially for stuff that will probably never be looked at again.)

Comment: Unless your "variable references" are all shorter than width allowed for controls, I doubt even screenshots will show everything.

Comment: You can always use the `SaveAsText` functionality. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/211210/7296893. That way, one can parse the text files to see which reports use which fields, or can choose to recreate the report from the text file.

Comment: @Andre : The requesting departments want the output in a PDF due to it making it easier for them to use the data for their jobs. (They need to mark-up the output and show certain things).

Comment: @BobS - Unfortunately, the formatting and layout matters to this export, so the textual descriptions of the values is not enough for their needs.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But when you have the screenshots, you can create a PDF from them, e.g.: https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-convert-multiple-images-into-pdf-files/

Comment: since no one mentioned it; why not use a form to load the report with settings.  add a setting to add a variables page somewhere in the report.